# Remove potion effects using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I made a horse race track and at the start everyone gets slowness. At the end when they cross the finish line I want them to lose this effect. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself?  Arqade works much better when there's an attempt made by the asker to solve their problem first.  We get more effort, you get a better answer, and everybody is happy.

Answer (score 6):

The command for getting rid of all effects is `/effect *player* clear`, so if you put a pressure plate or something on the finish line connected to a command block, the block command would be 
`effect @p clear`. If however your racers have other effects that you don't want to remove, use 
`effect @p 2 0`, which will remove slowness only.

Comment: @alixey999 No problem, if my answer works remember you can accept it by clicking the green tick mark :)

Comment: Instead of a pressure plate, I would just put the clearing command block on a 20Hz clock and use selectors to clear the effect from everyone within a specific area.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect clear *player*`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove slowness from a player using

```
/effect <player> 2 0
```

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect clear <player> slowness`

Answer (score -1):

Use /effect *player* clear 
This will clear all effects

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect clear player`